# android USBHost flash drive

Tags: android, usb

I am trying to make application for reading external storage file system connected using OTG cable to XOOM with ICS.
i am using this code to determine IN and OUT endpoint for communication with flash device

```
final UsbDeviceConnection connection = manager.openDevice(device);
UsbInterface inf = device.getInterface(0);
if (!connection.claimInterface(inf, true)) {
    Log.v("USB", "failed to claim interface");
}
UsbEndpoint epOut = null;
UsbEndpoint epIn = null;
// look for our bulk endpoints
for (int i = 0; i < inf.getEndpointCount(); i++) {
    UsbEndpoint ep = inf.getEndpoint(i);
    if (ep.getType() == UsbConstants.USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK) {
        if (ep.getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_OUT) {
            epOut = ep;
        } else {
            epIn = ep;
        }
    }
}
if (epOut == null || epIn == null) {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("not all endpoints found");
}
final UsbEndpoint inEndPoint = epIn;
```

it works normal.
then i am trying to read first 512 bytes to get FAT32 boot sector

```
ByteBuffer arg1 = ByteBuffer.allocate(512);
UsbRequest request = new UsbRequest();
request.initialize(connection, inEndPoint);
request.queue(arg1, inEndPoint.getMaxPacketSize());
UsbRequest result = connection.requestWait(); // halt here
connection.releaseInterface(inf);
connection.close();
```

but it does not read any data from connected device.
all this code run on separate thread after granding permission on device

```
PendingIntent mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(USBHostSampleActivity.this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);
manager.requestPermission(lDevices.get(position),mPermissionIntent);
```

in Broadcast receiver i just start new thread with previous code;
i also tried to make call to 
[USBDeviceConnection.controlTransfer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDeviceConnection.html#controlTransfer%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29)

```
byte[] b = new byte[0x10];
int cTransfer = connection.controlTransfer(128, 6, 16, 0,b, 12, 0);
```

like in libusb sample to get f0 data and/or hwstats but it always return -1
also i tried replace async request using USBRequst to sync bulkTransfers but result is the same.
Have anyone worked with this part of Android SDK?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar - connect a USB HID device to Xoom running ICS. After doing some research, I know that US-shipped Xooms most of the time have no problems with USB Host API but any other (e.g. EU or Australia-shipped) devices have Host API implemented in a way that doesn't allow to make a Control Transfer.I am trying to flash my device with different images, I'll let you know when I suceed. Have you find something useful since yesterday?

Comment: Yes, i almost finished implementing fat32 parsing using usbhost api. and i can tell you that you dont need to use controltransfer at all. all you need is bulk_transfer and HID official documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a library for that called libaums: https://github.com/mjdev/libaums

The library takes care of low level USB communication and implements the FAT32 file system. It also includes an example app. Listing a directory would work as follows:

```
UsbMassStorageDevice[] devices = UsbMassStorageDevice.getMassStorageDevices(this);
device.init();

// we only use the first device
device = devices[0];
// we always use the first partition of the device
FileSystem fs = device.getPartitions().get(0).getFileSystem();
Log.d(TAG, "Capacity: " + fs.getCapacity());
Log.d(TAG, "Occupied Space: " + fs.getOccupiedSpace());
Log.d(TAG, "Free Space: " + fs.getFreeSpace());
UsbFile root = fs.getRootDirectory();

for(UsbFile f : root.listFiles())
    Log.d(TAG, f.getName())
```

Comment: which one is the example app? Is it usbfileman? I tried to run app but app forced to close.

Comment: Yes usbfileman is the example application. Check the permissions and in the settings (example app does not make usage of the new Android runtime permission acquiring). If you have an error log, you can also submit an issue on github.

Answer (score 4):

It appears you are missing a whole protocol layer; you can't just read 512 bytes from the device. What should it send back? How could it know you want to start to read at the beginning of the disk?

How you actually read a memory location from USB-MSC device depends on the device sub class type and the supported transport protocol.

It is likely that an ordinary flash disk uses the [SCSI transparent command set](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/devclass_docs/uasp_1_0.zip) in conjunction with the [USB Mass Storage Class Bulk-Only (BBB) Transport](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/devclass_docs/usbmassbulk_10.pdf).

You have to examine the device descriptor to find out what your device supports. See also the [MSC device class overview](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/devclass_docs/Mass_Storage_Specification_Overview_v1.4_2-19-2010.pdf) for all possible values and references to their documentation.

Comment: Hey Alexander, I'm also trying to work on a similar app. Could you update your links please? They seem to be dead now.